# Update the content of an element on the parent after an action on the child component

Tags: reactjs

My goal is to allow child-elements to render any `JSX.Element` in a specific container in the parent.

Imagine a simple page with a main-content and a sidebar on the right hand side (details sidebar).

Now, depending on the element that was clicked, I want to leave the control of whether the sidebar should be displayed at all and the content of it to the child itself.

```js
<Page>
  <Page.Header>
    <Header />
  </Page.Header>
  <Page.Sidebar dismissed={sidebarElement == null}>{sidebarElement}</Page.Sidebar>
  <Page.Main>
    <Outlet />
  </Page.Main>
  <Page.DetailView dismissed={detailsElement == null}>{detailsElement}</Page.DetailView>
</Page>
```

One way I was able to do this was by providing a `PageContextProvider`like so:

```js
<PageContextProvider
  updateSidebar={(element) => setSidebarElement(element)}
  updateDetails={(element) => setDetailsElement(element)}
>
  <Page>
    <Page.Header>
      <Header />
    </Page.Header>
    <Page.Sidebar dismissed={sidebarElement == null}>{sidebarElement}</Page.Sidebar>
    <Page.Main>
      <Outlet />
    </Page.Main>
    <Page.DetailView dismissed={detailsElement == null}>{detailsElement}</Page.DetailView>
  </Page>
</PageContextProvider>
```

However, the disadvantage here is that I need to use a `setTimeout()` like so:

```js
const updateSidebar = useContext(PageContext).updateSidebar;
const updateDetails = useContext(PageContext).updateDetail;

setTimeout(() => {
  updateSidebar(<div>Sidbar</div>);
  updateDetails(<div>Details</div>);
};
```

Otherwise I would get an exception stating that it is not possible to re-render the parent while the child is still being rendered (which makes sense of course).

So, is there a better solution to this which would allow me to update other components but without having to resort back to `setTimeout()`?